# Cannot find symbol, Cannot figure out why this error is occurring

Tags: java, bluej

When linking to variables of a super class:
FirstName
LastName
StreetAddress
PostCode
PhoneNumber

the code works fine, but if I add in three extra variables of a sub class
DepartmentName
TFN
AnnualSalary

The variables cant be found, bluej however, VISUALLY is connected to the sub class.

I would just get rid of the extra variables but if I do my code doesn't compile, so right now, the variables are there but not being used completely.

Code:

array list

```
private ArrayList<Person> myShopEmployee = new ArrayList<Person>();
    private JFrame frame;

    private JLabel labFirstName;   
    private JTextField txtFirstName;

    private JLabel labLastName;   
    private JTextField txtLastName;

    private JLabel labStreetAddress;   
    private JTextField txtStreetAddress;

    private JLabel labPostCode;   
    private JTextField txtPostCode;

    private JLabel labPhoneNumb;   
    private JTextField txtPhoneNumb;

    private JLabel labDepartmentName;   
    private JTextField txtDepartmentName;

    private JLabel labTFN;   
    private JTextField txtTFN;

    private JLabel labAnnualSalary;   
    private JTextField txtAnnualSalary;

    private int index = 0;
```

If I remove the extra variables from this line of code, and the above array my code does not compile.

```
class creatingShopEmployeeListener implements ActionListener 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                            "example", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

                                          ShopEmployee newShopEmployee = new ShopEmployee (txtFirstName.getText(),txtLastName.getText(),txtStreetAddress.getText(),txtPostCode.getText(),txtPhoneNumb.getText(),txtDepartmentName.getText(),txtTFN.getText(),txtAnnualSalary.getText());
                                          myShopEmployee.add(newShopEmployee);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                            "ShopEmployee has been created" );


            }
        }
```

this is where the cannot find symbol error occurs, if the above two code samples stay as they are. (here i have TFN, but the error happens with any of the  three variables.)

```
 class seeShopEmployeeListener implements ActionListener 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                     if (myShopEmployee.size() > 0) 
                     {

                         ShopEmployee curShopEmployee = (ShopEmployee) myShopEmployee.get(index);
                         txtFirstName.setText(curShopEmployee.getFirstName());
                         txtLastName.setText(curShopEmployee.getLastName() );
                         txtStreetAddress.setText(curShopEmployee.getStreetAddress() );
                         txtPostCode.setText(curShopEmployee.getPostCode() );
                         txtPhoneNumb.setText(curShopEmployee.getPhoneNumb() );
                         txtTFN.setText(curShopEmployee.getTFN() );
                     if ( index < myShopEmployee.size() -1 ) { index ++; }
                     else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                "No ShopEmployee" );
                            } 
                }
            }
        }
```

and finally this is the ShopEmployee class

```
public class ShopEmployee extends Person
{
    //creating variables
    private String departmentName;
    private String TFN, annualSalary;
    public ShopEmployee()//ShopEmployee constructor
    {

        //setting values for the new variables
        departmentName = "";
        TFN = "";
        annualSalary = "";

    }
    public ShopEmployee(String myFirstName, String myLastName, String myStreetAddress, String myPostCode, String myPhoneNumb, String myDepartmentName, String myTFN, String myAnnualSalary)//ShopEmployee constructor which contains these variables
    {

        super(myFirstName,myLastName,myStreetAddress,myPostCode,myPhoneNumb);
        departmentName = myDepartmentName;
        TFN = myTFN;
        annualSalary = myAnnualSalary;

    }
    //setting up the variables
     public void setDepartmentName(String myDepartmentName)
    {
        setDepartmentName(myDepartmentName);
    }
    public void setTFN(String myTFN)
    {
        setTFN(myTFN);
    }
    public void setAnnualSalary(String myAnnualSalary)
    {
        setAnnualSalary(myAnnualSalary);
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString() + ", TFN is " + TFN + ", Annual Salary is " + annualSalary + ", and Department Name is " + departmentName;//returns the super variable string which includes the name phone number ect then adds on the new variables
    }
}
```

Thank you. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't you think the exact error message could help finding what the problem is?

Comment: cannot find symbol method getTFN()

Comment: That's not the exact error message. The exact error message says at which line of which file the error occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not added the getters for the new fields TFN & departmentName. As the two variables are declared private so can't access them directly either. You are trying to call the getter

> curShopEmployee.getTFN()

but that method does not exist in your class.

Comment: I think this worked, I went back and set a get for the departmentName variable and the error did not show up, I will do it for all 3 and try making them work, and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Alright thanks, that worked, fixed 2 issues, the extra variables are in the GUI and it doesn't crash because of missing variables, many thanks.